# Misusing istream& get

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a method for extracting email info from an external file and store it in a string. I'm using .get to extract the characters, but my debugger is saying: no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list. It's also saying that it can't convert the third parameter from const char[2] to char. This seems like a quick fix, but I've been playing around with the parameters and can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

current->email_data.sent is a pointer to a character array.

Also, I'm not sure why my code won't indent when I paste it here.

```
int Classify::Load_email(char filename[]) {
email_node * current;
current = email_head;  
ifstream source_file(filename);
if(email_head)
{
    while(current->next) {
        current = current->next;
    }

}
else {
    email_head = new email_node;
}
while(!source_file.eof()) {
    source_file.get(current->email_data.sent, 200, "|");
}
};
```

Comment: when copying code try using a text editor like Notepad++ to indent it an initial 4 space so that the format is picked up as code, much easier than going through each line and spacing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the three-parameter overload of `basic_istream::get`, the last parameter is a single character, not a string. Replace `"|"` with `'|'`.

Comment: Thought it was something silly like that. Thank you.